# Linearize specific node of XML/HTML document for vertical editing on Notepad++

Tags: html, xml, notepad++

In order to easily modify in vertical selection a huge number of cells in the table in one Selection with a vertical paste. (the paste on each line is from a list which has different value on each line).

I would like to do it inside Notepad++ only without the need to program anything.

What I have from the start is normal <Tbody> content of a table like this :

```
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            MachineType 
        </td>
        <td>
            Yt_GP_MachineType
        </td>
        <td/>
        <td>
            MyMachine.MachineType
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Variant 
        </td>
        <td>
            Yt_GP_Variant
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            MyMachine.Variant
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Emulation
        </td>
        <td>
            Yt_GP_Emulation
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            MyMachine.Emulation
        </td>
    </tr>
```

And I would like to have a macro that linearize and align all <tr> nodes and below in a single line like this :

```
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>    MachineType </td><td>   Yt_GP_MachineType   </td><td></td><td>  MyMachine.MachineType   </td></tr>
    <tr><td>    Variant     </td><td>   Yt_GP_Variant       </td><td></td><td>  MyMachine.Variant       </td></tr>
    <tr><td>    Emulation   </td><td>   Yt_GP_Emulation     </td><td></td><td>  MyMachine.Emulation     </td></tr>
```

Note: the auto alignment of each <td> & </td> nodes is important and the "Code alignment" plugin of Notepad++ doesn't work if I mentioned align by... (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>) "<" for my part. Currently I'm doing this manually...

Note 2 : Linearize or Pretty print from XML Tool plug in doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239)

Comment: @Toto Done, thanks for the note. If you have any solution suggestion to my issue, I would be happy to hear about it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short story - IMHO you should write a script in your favorite scripting language.

BTW - spaces within `<tr>...</tr>` only makes manual editing easier and should be replaced by the use of CSS e.g. `<tbody style="vertical-align:center;text-align:center"><tr style="height:100px">`

But if you really want to do a special linearize with Notepad++, here is the man's way on Windows. For other operating systems you have to adapt this.

1. Tidy up different (!) tags like `<td/>`. Find what: `<td/>`, Replace with: `<td></td>`
2. Tidy trailing space (see your HTML snippet posted): From main menu *Edit > Blank Operations  > Trim Trailing Space*
3. Tidy tabs vs. space (see your HTML snippet posted): From main menu *Edit > Blank Operations  > TAB to Space*
4. From main menu Plugins > XML Tools > Linearize
5. RegEx Make single lines: Find what: `<tr>`, Replace with: `\r\n<tr>`
6. RegEx Expand lines (only change `tr`to `td`): Find what: `<td>`, Replace with: `\r\n<td>`
7. Go to begin of first line e.g <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>Pos1</kbd>
8. Align: Plugins > Code alignment > Align by...`</td>` (It may be necessary for you to install the plugin.)
9. If really necessary (for your needs only) insert two spaces. Uncheck Wrap around and try single replace first! Find what: `<td>`, Replace with: `<td>`  . Please note the two space here!
10. Repeat (4) - From main menu Plugins > XML Tools > Linearize
11. Repeat (5) - RegEx Make single lines: Find what: `<tr>`, Replace with: `\r\n<tr>`

All this is resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, just one precision, "Linearize" transform all the empty line from <td></td> to <td/>. Then this needs to be redo every time linearize is used. And regarding step 11. In order to put back into one line I had to do the \r\n reverse way around, but I understood the logic and it's fine!

Comment: You're welcome. If an answer has helped you solve your problem feel free to mark the answer as accepted. You should also consider voting it up.